# Generating a unique ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, algorithm

I want to implement a saving system similar to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) where if a user presses a button a unique 5 character value is returned. Here is what I have so far:

The database backend uses auto-incrementing ID's starting at `5308416`. I use a modified Radix function (see below) to convert these numerical ID's into characters. I use a reverse function to lookup character ID's back to numerical database ID's.

```
function genID (value)
{
    var alphabet = "23456789BCDFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZbcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz";

    var result = "";
    var length = alphabet.length;

    while (value > 0)
    {
        result = alphabet[value % length] + result;
        value  = Math.floor (value / length);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that these generated ID's are very much predictable. My question is, how can I make the generated ID's seem random but still unique (so I can look them up in the database as numbers). I was thinking of using some encryption algorithm but not sure where to start. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated (maybe there is a better way of doing this also).

Comment: use time it is unique and never get repeated !

Comment: Except when the clock is changed manually, or automatically adjusts for DST and other one-second leap...

Comment: As **Zied Jaballah** said, I think time should do it `var uniq = (new Date).getTime();`

Comment: ... or if you create two IDs within one millisecond. (This could happen if you create a bunch of IDs within a loop.)

Comment: Why do you have to convert from the database generated IDs to characters?  And, why can't the conversion to a string just be the string representation of the number?  I understand the rest of the question, but I'm not understanding why this extra complication is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to be able to go both ways (i.e. convert an integer to it's hash and back again)? If you can store the hash and lookup the content that way, then it's relatively easy to create a function that produces a hard-to-guess, but complete hash space. You use primes to generate a sequence that only repeats once all possible permutations are exhausted.

The following PHP example is [from my own code](https://github.com/hamishcampbell/silverstripe-pastie/blob/e0643cfcee87aa9597a3babc62c136bb1250ce3f/code/PastieSnippet.php#L157), adapted from [this site](http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash):

```
function hash($len = 6) {
    $base = 36;
    $gp = array(1,23,809,28837,1038073,37370257 /*,1345328833*/);
    $maxlen = count($gp);
    $len = $len > ($maxlen-1) ? ($maxlen-1) : $len;
    while($len < $maxlen && pow($base,$len) < $this->ID) $len++; 
    if($len >= $maxlen) throw new Exception($this->ID." out of range (max ".pow($base,$maxlen-1).")");
    $ceil = pow($base,$len);
    $prime = $gp[$len];
    $dechash = ($this->ID * $prime) % $ceil;
    $hash = base_convert($dechash, 10, $base);
    return str_pad($hash, $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

It would be easy enough to implement that in JavaScript, but ideally you wouldn't need too - you'd have an insert trigger on your table that populated a hash field with the result of that algorithm (adapted for SQL, of course).

Comment: This is a really good solution. Here is a node.js implementation: https://github.com/alecgorge/node-psuedohash

Answer (score 0):

A non-predictable, but unique ID can be made by combining your server-side auto-incrementing number with either a current date/time nugget or with a random number.  The server-side auto-incrementing number guarantees uniqueness and the date/time nugget or random number removes the predictability.

For a unique ID in string form that takes the server-side unique number as input and where you add the date/time nugget on the client you can do this:

```
function genID(serverNum) {
    return(serverNum + "" + (new Date).getTime());
}
```

Or using a random number:

```
function genID(serverNum) {
    return(serverNum + "" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000));
}
```

But, it might be best to add the date/time element on the server and just store that whole unique ID in the database there.

Comment: The random number generator in Javascript is just awful. The number of collisions is pretty large.

Comment: @Dave - This algorithm doesn't care if there are collisions in the random number generator (there will be with any random number generator).  If you read the post, the uniqueness comes from the server-generated number.  The addition of the random number just makes the overall number not predictable.